# How to get the result from Prolog, via the C++ FFI , into a C++ variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

The problem I have is how to get and store (variables `X` and `Y`) from Prolog (via interface from SWI-Prolog) into a variable (C++) in Visual Studio

In short: I codified a puzzle with triangular tiles into a Prolog representation. This puzzle is solved by Prolog. This works so far. The visual representation with each tile is done in Visual Studio. This is working also.

Now I want to call via interface the Prolog engine and get the solution and each step (rotate tile/which tile/and its location) during the process (done by `write/1` in Prolog). So far I can get prolog to call the function and get the return value in a console window. Also I get displayed each `write()` in the console. BUT only in the console.

Prolog part: 
X represents a list with IDs of puzzle tiles. 
Y represents a list of rotate states of the tiles as a result of prolog
internally the tiles are represented as:

teil(ID, side_a, side_b, side_c).

```
teil(8, lsh, hbsh, gsv).
```

Prolog call:

```
?- puFlaeche(X,Y).
X = [2, 7, 3, 5, 9, 1, 4, 6, 8],
Y = [rechts, rechts, unten, rechts, rechts, unten, rechts, unten, rechts].
```

Visual Studio:

```
if( ! PL_initialise(1,av) ) {
    Console::Write("eeor with PL_initialise(1,av)");
} else {
    Console::Write("no error with PL_initialise(1,av)");
}

PlCall("consult('puzzle.pl')");
char rval2;
predicate_t pred2 = PL_predicate("puFlaeche",2,"user");
term_t h2 = PL_new_term_refs(2);
char * variable1 = "X";
char * variable2 = "Y";
//add some Variable to prolog
PL_put_variable(h2);
PL_put_variable(h2+1);
//produce console output
rval2 = PL_call_predicate(NULL,PL_Q_NORMAL,pred2,h2);
```

If I call:

```
if (PL_call(h2, NULL)) {
    PL_get_list_chars(h2, &fact2,
        CVT_ATOM|REP_UTF8);
}
```

I see in debug from VS at breakpoint that fact2 somehow store the result:

```
fact2   0x05699460 "\x2\a\x3\x5\t\x1\x4\x6\b"   char *
```

And its also displayed in console... but with example output:

```
ERROR: source_sink 2 does not exist
ERROR: source_sink 7 does not exist
ERROR: source_sink 3 does not exist
...
```

and if I call:

```
term_t tail = PL_copy_term_ref(h2);
term_t head = PL_new_term_ref();
int x;
while(PL_get_list(tail, head, tail))
{
    PL_get_integer(head, &x);
    Console::WriteLine("Ergebnis 2:---"+x+"---| ");
}
```

I get indeed the solution (from X) somehow without error in the console:

```
"some debug text": 2 
"some debug text": 7
"some debug text": 3
...
```

I tried several other solutions but this is so far the best result I have so far... 
After long text questions again:

A) <strike>how to get Y variable content from Prolog</strike> SOLVED Below

----EDIT QUESTION------

B) how to get the write() from prolog which is displayed in console or any other way to get a step by step output like "trace" in prolog

C) how to store A) and the write() statements into a variable or list in c++

I may run into a wrong approach... so you can help me out.
Thanks in advance :)

---

## EDIT

A) I get the content of the X and Y list by calling the function `PL_get_list` 
for X which represents the IDs of the tilws //thanks also to Jan

```cpp
term_t tail = PL_copy_term_ref(h2);
term_t head = PL_new_term_ref();
int x;
while(PL_get_list(tail, head, tail))
{
    PL_get_integer(head, &x);
    PL_get_integer(head+1, &x);
    Console::WriteLine("Ergebnis X :---"+x+"---| ");
}
```

And for Y which represent the rotate state

```cpp
term_t tail1 = PL_copy_term_ref(h2+1);
term_t head1 = PL_new_term_ref();
std::string extracted_state_array[10];
char* state_array[10];int count=0;

while(PL_get_list(tail1, head1, tail1)){
    std::string st;
    PL_get_chars(head1,&state_array[count],CVT_ALL | CVT_WRITE | BUF_RING);
    st.assign(state_array[count],strlen(state_array[count]));
    extracted_state_array[count]=st;

    std::cout<<"Ergebnis Y :---"+extracted_state_array[count]+"---| "<<  std::endl;
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Up to `PL_call_predicate()`, all is fine.   Now, `h2` is an array of two term references, `h2+0` bound to `[2, 7, 3, 5, 9, 1, 4, 6, 8]` and `h2+1` to `[rechts, rechts, unten, rechts, rechts, unten, rechts, unten, rechts]`.   Then you do something strange: you *call* `h2+0`, basically calling

```
call([2, 7, 3, 5, 9, 1, 4, 6, 8])
```

The list is an abbreviation for consult/1, so you try to consult (load) files named `1`, etc.  Hence the messages.

You need to use the list iteration methods from `PlList` class to enumerate the elements in the array.  Then you can translate each to a number or string (for the second).

When embedding (in C++) you will normally not use Prolog's I/O.  You can translate individual terms to a string using `PL_get_chars()` and variations.  If you really want to rebind I/O, there is the header `SWI-Stream.h`.  Its usage is mostly undocumented though.  You can look through the source code for examples re-binding Prolog's I/O to read/write to the `swipl-win.exe` console, etc.  I do not think that is what you are after though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. your right. i tried paralel also Pl_List. I update my question or should i answer my question? Sorry its my first post :/ I have now a List for X and a List for Y. Now do yu may have anny sugestions for how to get the write() output or maybe "trace" from prolog? For this purpos you propose SWI-Stream.h am i Right? Is there another way? Maybe "PL_backtracec" ? Im not shure... My plan is that c++ will process the step by step output delivered by prolog(trace-like) and display the changes in the GUI element

Comment: do you have anny hint for me to redirect the trace output to a variable in c++? May how to start with SWI-Stream.h or in another way. I opened another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56408112/how-to-redirect-prologoutput-from-pl-call-predicate-function-inclusive-traceo) especialy for this last part. All the other parts of my project work, except this one. I would be very grateful if you could help me

Comment: This is a bit unrelated question.  You can redefine I/O using SWI-Stream.h.  This is largely undocumented.  See src/pl-ntmain.c and packages/swipl-win in the sources for some examples.